# Basic iTunes AppleScript issue

Tags: applescript, itunes

Feeling like a real bone-head here, just trying to figure how how I can get this script to insert the name from the selection in artist and put it into Album artists.

```
tell application "iTunes"
  set theTracks to (item 1 of (get selection))
  set theTracks to selection
  repeat with theTrack in theTracks
    set albumartist to artist of theTrack
  end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set theTracks to (item 1 of (get selection))
    set theTracks to selection
    repeat with theTrack in theTracks
        set albumartist to artist of theTrack
        set album artist of theTrack to albumartist -- the missing line
    end repeat
end tell
```

In real life I would probably skip the intermediate variable and write the pair of lines as one line, like this:

```
        set album artist of theTrack to (get artist of theTrack)
```

Or even better:

```
        tell theTrack to set album artist to (get artist)
```